# Retrieving a form field hidden value thats located in table cell <td>

Tags: javascript, html-table

I have a table with a cell that contains a hidden input type.  How do you go about accessing the value of this hidden input type?

HTML Table:

```
<table id = "tableId">
  <tr>
    <td>FirstName LastName</td>
    <td><input type="hidden" value="userId" /><td>
  </tr>
```

Javascript

```
    var table= document.getElementById("tableId");
    var tblTR = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (var i = 0; i<tblTR.length; i ++) {
        var tr = tblTR[i];
        var tds = tr.getElementsByTagName("td");
        console.debug(tds[0]); //gets the whole cell
        console.debug(tds[1].innerHTML); //gets content of cell, but not the actual value of the hidden input
}
```

With the second console.debug statement, the value I'm looking for is "userId" and not

```
<input type="hidden" value="userId" />
```

From what I understand, a [td element cannot have a value attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-td-element), therefore I can't simply just do a **tds[i].value;**.

Alternatively, is there another approach that can be used to store this hidden value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
    if (inputs[i].type == 'hidden'){
        alert(inputs[i].value);
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U53Kg/).

I'd suggest assigning the `inputs[i].value` to a variable, or an array, though rather than simply `alert()`-ing it:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var values;

for (i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
    if (inputs[i].type == 'hidden'){
        values = inputs[i].value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doh!  I never knew I could also iterate through a td's child elements!  Thank you for the response.  All other answers below work too, however, I forgot to mention that these cells are created(and removed) dynamically, and therefore assigning a unique id or name was not in my thought process.

Answer (score 2):

You need to walk to the input tag itself

```
hiddenInputs = tds[1].getElementsByTagName("input");
console.debug(hiddenInputs[0].value);
```

or have a unique name or unique id to it and then you can access it directly.

```
<td><input type="hidden" id="inp1" value="userId" /><td>

document.getElementById("inp1").value

<td><input type="hidden" name="inp1" value="userId" /><td>

document.forms[0].inp1.value
```

Comment: Best answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Give your input tag a name

example:

```
<input type="hidden" value="userId" name='userId'/>
```

Then you can access it:

```
<form ...name='theform'>
...

<input type="hidden" value="userId" name='userId'/>
...

</form>
```

The Javascript

```
var value = document.theform.userId.value;
```

this should do, you can ignore the table cells