# Form in ajax loaded content does not work

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I have a page which loads content from a different file `(content.php)` into a div and reloads it every 5 seconds.
In the content.php file I am using a form (simple HTML without javascript). When I access the file directly `(example.com/content.php)` the form works, but when I load it into a div of a different page with ajax, I cannot click the button.
How can I modify the form that the button is clickable when the file is loaded into a div?

Thats the form in content.php:

```
echo ("<form action='submit.php' method='GET'>");
echo ("<input type='hidden' name = 'value' value = '".$value1."'>");
echo ("<input type='hidden' name = 'value2' value = '".$value2."'>");
echo ("<button class='button-1' type='submit'>".$button_text."</button></form>");`
```

This form code is in a for-loop, so there are several buttons.

Comment: Could you show us the code you're using?

Comment: Can you include some examples of the code that you are using. Without more information it's hard to answer the question

Comment: Thats the form in content.php: 
echo ("<form action='submit.php' method='GET'>");
    echo ("<input type='hidden' name = 'value' value = '".$value1."'>");
    echo ("<input type='hidden' name = 'value2' value = '".$value2."'>");
    echo ("<button class='button-1' type='submit'>".$button_text."    </button></form>");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding of your question, you are loading a form from page contact.php on to a different page using ajax and that is working correctly. However, clicking the submit button on the form created in this second page doesn't do anything?

Have you tried assigning an onclick event to the submit and console logging the data? If you're testing in chrome, are there an errors that pop up in the inspect element?

Are you passing the php response as JSON or just echoing out all the input elements? I'm assuming that the form is being passed by echoing out the elements like so:

```html
echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit'/>";
```

You could try in your php

```html
echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit' onclick='testFunc()'/>";
```

and in your javascript create the function:

```js
function testFunc() {
  alert('Submit button clicked');

  //log whatever input values you want passed to the server replace sampleInput1 with whatever id you are using for the inputs
  console.log(document.getElementById('sampleInput1').value);


}
```

If the alert pops up and the input logs ok, from there just create another ajax call to submit your form, if you want to stay on that page. Alternatively, check the `<form>` tag what is the action and method?

Alright after rereading your code add `id='hidVal1'` and `id='hidVal2'`to your hidden inputs like so:

```js
    echo("<input type='hidden' id='hidVal1' name = 'value' value = '".$value1.
      "'>");
    echo("<input type='hidden' id='hidVal2' name = 'value2' value = '".$value2.
      "'>");
```

I am assuming that you know how to make an ajax function, so to create the values to send use the `testFunc()` I suggested and make it like so:

```js
function testFunc() {
  alert('Submit button clicked');
  var hidVal1 = document.getElementById('hidVal1').value;
  var hidVal2 = document.getElementById('hidVal2').value;

  //log for testing
  console.log("value of hidden 1 " + hidVal1 + "value of hidden 2 " + hidVal2);

  //url for ajax
  var url = "submit.php?hidVal1=" + hidVal1 "&hidVal2="+
  hidVal2;

  //call to ajax function

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I click the Button the alert displays. But the console shows "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Comment: One problem, the IDs are generated by a for loop. When I am submitting the form I need the value with one ID, so I have to tell the function which button was clicked. onclick='testFunc('id')' and then using this in the function does not work.

Comment: Alrighty. In that case it is probably better to access elements by name. names can repeat in a form, but not id's. The idea is that you can have multiple inputs stored in a name like an array. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220914/retrieving-a-form-field-hidden-value-thats-located-in-table-cell-td) Does a good job explaining how to access hidden elements by tag name. Hope that helps.